# Network - Ubuntu Server 16.04 cant connect using ethernet

Tags: 16.04, networking, server

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm having issues connecting.

When I do ping www.ubuntu.com, I get unknown host.

If I do ifconfig:

```
enp2s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 70:85:c2:01:50:0f
inet6 addr:fe80::7285::c2ff:fe01::500f/64 Scope Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU"1500 Metric:1
RX packets: 172 errors:0 ...srry im manually typing this
TX packets....
```

Now, I did some searches on similar issues, and some of them involve checking /etc/network/interfaces, which displays as follow, I've tested changing it to static, but both my attempts have failed(static and DHCP):

as Static:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

As DHCP, the only thing that changes is:

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Restarted services after changes and what not.

Additional useful information:

For some reason 'sudo service network-manager restart' outputs Unit network-manager.services not found.

I also took a look at [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371247) but didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?!

Also, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Does `tcpdump -n -i enp2s0` show any traffic?

Comment: 0 packets captured when i tried.
Turns out after changing ethernet cable and changing the ip address on the static configuration helped. I have a connection now.

Answer (score 0):

Considering **enp2s0** is your network interface try these:

```
sudo ip link set dev enp2s0 down
sudo dhclient enp2s0
```

Comment: Should I do sudo ip link set dev enp2s0 up after your last command?
no output got displayed after dhclient enp2s0 but I did try to pin www.google.com and still unknown host

Comment: Those 2 should be enough (they reset your network interface).  Make sure what is exactly your network interface by "sudo lshw -class network"

Comment: I did sudo lshw -class network and I do see logical name: enp2s0 but after the commands you posted I still try to do ping www.google.com and same result, unknown host...

Comment: seems to be a hardware issue

Comment: hmmm its a brand new motherboard  and I do see the lights up, could it be a driver of some sort?

Comment: ok figured that I should change the ethernet cable, didnt seem to resolve before.
Now, I run sudo dhclient enp2s0 and get the following:
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv/conf

Comment: And I'm still unable to ping www.ubuntu.com nor google.com